# Iframe Component is Blank on Streamlit Cloud Deploy

Tags: iframe, streamlit

I am having trouble getting an iframe to display correctly on my private Streamlit Cloud deployed app.

I am trying to [embed a Metabase dashboard](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/12-public-links.html#sharing-and-embedding-dashboards-or-questions) inside my Streamlit app. Locally, the iframe works just fine (pictured).

The example iframe from the Streamlit docs is loading in my Streamlit Cloud deployed app, but not my Metabase iframe.

Here is the code used to display my iframe (I made replicated this scenario with dummy data so you can test the code) and my Streamlit version

`streamlit==1.10.0`

```
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import streamlit as st
st.write("Streamlit Docs Example iframe")
components.iframe("https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest")
st.write("different iframe test")
components.iframe(src="http://smb-analytics-metabase.herokuapp.com/public/dashboard/afefddda-d5d4-43ed-83fd-307eab7ded3c", width=1285, height=1000, scrolling=True)
```

I have tried:

- Chrome and Brave browsers
- Using `components.html()` inplace of `components.iframe()`
- Removing the `width=1285, height=1000, scrolling=True` arguements of components.iframe()
- Rebooting my Streamlit Cloud App Deleting and Rebuilding my Streamlit Cloud App

None of these things got the iframe to load on the deployed app. Anyone know of a fix ?

**Locally**
[image: Local Streamlit App with working iframe]

**Streamlit Cloud**
[image: Streamlit Cloud Deployed App with bug]

[Link to Streamlit discussion board](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/iframe-component-is-blank-on-streamlit-cloud-deploy/27523)

[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/4947)

[Link to Discord discussion](https://discord.com/channels/840324946076106802/880498183233482792/996079422648094770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with mixed-content:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://.streamlitapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://smb-analytics-metabase.herokuapp.com/public/dashboard/afefddda-d5d4-43ed-83fd-307eab7ded3c'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The solution is to ensure that all embedded content has `https://` links, which the final line of code starting with `components.iframe(src="http://...` does not currently.

[Answer and discussion of Chrome Developer tools on Streamlit forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/iframe-component-is-blank-on-streamlit-cloud-deploy/27523/2?u=randyzwitch)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the link I was trying to use was http instead of https which is required by Streamlit.

Many props to Randy Zwitch from the Streamlit Team !

[Full answer here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/iframe-component-is-blank-on-streamlit-cloud-deploy/27523/2)